# Point location in the end of RTL sentence with a last English word

Tags: right-to-left

When the last word(s) in RTL sentence is an English one, the point at the end of the sentence (also termed full point/full stop/period) is in the wrong location.
[image]

The MWE is as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{polyglossia,bidi}
\setmainlanguage{hebrew}
\setotherlanguage{english}
\setmainfont{David}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}
 \item שלום hello שלום.
 \item שלום hello.
 \item שלום hello .
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

Can it be fixed somehow?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to explicitly change the language to English:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{hebrew}
\setotherlanguage{english}
\setmainfont{Linux Libertine O}
\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}
  \item שלום \textenglish{hello} שלום.
  \item שלום \textenglish{hello}.
  \item שלום \textenglish{hello}.
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

Or, if you are brave you can use `babel` with `lualatex`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[nil,bidi=basic-r]{babel}
\babelprovide[import=he,main]{hebrew}
\babelprovide[import=en-AU]{australian}
\babelfont{rm}{Linux Libertine O}
\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}
  \item שלום hello שלום.
  \item שלום hello.
  \item שלום hello.
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

Output is the same:

[image]